# Fourier Transform Form: two sin components & a phase shift & a magnitude for only one term

Tags: fourier-transform

This is an example from my text book of a continuous signal:
$$x_{in}(t)=\sin \left( 2\pi \cdot 1000 \cdot t\right) + 0.5\sin \left( 2\pi \cdot 2000 \cdot t + \dfrac{3\pi}{4} \right) $$
So to perform a fourier transform on this signal, how to do that, isn't it a bit funny, since it has two sine components. Shouldn't complex numbers have a sine term and a cosine term? And it's got a scalar term applied to only one component, don't those usually apply across both terms of a complex component? And it's phase shifted, what to do about that?

Comment: actually that equation is inconsequential isn't it? since we don't perform an FT on that, we'll just have a bunch of numbers, supposedly generated from those, and it's on those # that we perform the foueier transform operation isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the Fourier transform and evaluating the integral?

Comment: Another hint: $\cos(w t + \phi) = \cos(\phi) \cos(wt)-\sin(\phi) \sin(wt)$

Comment: yeah I just need to actually plug in for N and calculate everything out isn't it?

Comment: yea sometimes working through the maths can give you a real feel for what is going on

Comment: oh and the other good identity is $\cos t = (e^{i t} + e^{-i t})/2$

Answer (score 4):

Fourier Transform is a linear one, so you can make use of superposition principle:

$$ \mathscr{F} [\alpha x(t) + \beta y(t)] = \alpha \mathscr{F}[x(t)] + \beta \mathscr{F}[y(t)] $$

So for the **first component** $$x(t) = \sin \left( 2\pi \cdot 1000 \cdot t\right)$$

by [**definition**](http://www.mechmat.ethz.ch/Lectures/tables.pdf):

$$\mathscr{F}\left[\sin(2\pi f_0 t + \phi) \right] = \dfrac{i}{2} \left[ e^{-i \phi}\delta(f+f_0) - e^{i \phi}\delta(f-f_0) \right] $$

you get:

$$ \mathscr{F}[x(t)]=\dfrac{i}{2} \left[ \delta(f+1000) - \delta(f-1000) \right]  $$

**Second component** is a sinusoid with shifted phase, so the complex exponent represents that:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} \sin \left( 2\pi \cdot 2000 \cdot t + \dfrac{3\pi}{4} \right)$$

has following Fourier Transform:

$$\mathscr{F}[y(t)] = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{i}{2} \left[ e^{\dfrac{-3\pi i}{4}}\delta(f+2000) - e^{\dfrac{3\pi i}{4}}\delta(f-2000) \right] $$

By summing both results you get the Fourier Transform of your signal.